# angular-stl-model-viewer not updating Textures

Tags: angular, three.js

I'm currently trying to set up a basic .stl viewer with the possibility to preview different materials on the model itself. I have Angular 9 as framework and the whole .stl showing part is working quite fine and easy. When I try to update the Material it's simply not updating it, but showing a very strange basic material I assume. Like mentioned in the heading I'm currently using a GitHub project based on Three.js which can be found here: https://github.com/tevim/angular-stl-model-viewer

Like mentioned in the Three documentation I tried to set the `material.needsUpdate` and also the `texture.needsUpdate` flag, both without any effect.

---

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MeshOptions } from 'angular-stl-model-viewer';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Vector3, MeshBasicMaterial, TextureLoader, Texture } from 'three';
import { Subscribable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  meshOptions: MeshOptions = {
    scale: new Vector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01),
  };

  material: MeshBasicMaterial;

  constructor() {
    THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let texture = new TextureLoader().load(
      './assets/textures/prusa_pla_galaxy_black.jpg'
    );

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    console.log(texture);

    this.material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
    });

    this.material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
}
```

---

### app.component.html

```html
<stl-model-viewer [meshOptions]="meshOptions"
                  [material]="material"
                  stlModel="./assets/test/test2.stl" 
                  #stlViewer></stl-model-viewer>
```

---

### app.component.scss

```css
stl-model-viewer {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL file format does not support texture coordinates. And without these data, it's not possible to apply texture to your meshes.